Is there a category theory equivalent of pure type systems?
I have seen the correspondence between the simply-typed lambda calculus and Cartesian closed categories, and am curious about how this generalizes to other lambda calculi. I have seen some related writing, for instance this nLab page categorical semantics of dependent type theory or this paper Syntactic categories for dependent type theory: sketching and adequacy.
These sources providing multiple category-theoretic formulations of dependent types is initially surprising to me, and (at least from the perspective of a category theory beginner) they seem to use very disconnected machinery. This brings me to my question: is there some category theory equivalent to the way we vary sorts/axioms/rules with pure type systems?
